# SASS - Unable to cancel folder watch

Tags: css, terminal, sass

I'm new to SASS and as such ran `sass --watch dir` on my /scss directory.

Then I discovered Compass and ran `compass watch` on the same directory.

Now when I edit style.scss, the `compass watch` updates the /css/style.css file as expected, and the `sass watch` creates a new style.css alongside the style.scss file (which is unwanted).

I managed to cancel the `compass watch` with Ctrl+C. However even after a full system restart the `sass watch` still seems to be active. I.E. it's still creating style.css in the /scss directory.

How can I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.

Its turns out I had the Sublime Text SASS Build Package installed which was running all along.

I've uninstalled that and now everything is as it should be.

Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Oh ! You don't have to use Sass and compass at the same time dude.

Compass is a SASS extension, so you can use it alone.

Personally i advice you to learn SASS first so forget Compass for few months.

For the directory problem it's simple. Open your terminal go into the folder youre working.

Image you have a folder named site1 with a sass and a css subfolder. Go into your the site1 folder and run :
`sass --watch sass/style.scss:css/style.css`

And normaly it should work :)